# Is a Hong Kong SAR passport holder, with a USA working visa (L-1), and an APEC Business Travel card, eligible to apply for the Global Entry Program?

Tags: usa, international-travel, global-entry, abtc

Is a Hong Kong Special Administrative Region passport holder, with a USA working visa (L-1), and an APEC Business Travel card, eligible to apply for the Global Entry Program?

If not, is there any appropriate fast-entry program that I can apply?

Comment: APEC Business Travel cardholders can use the air crew lane at US immigration when entering as a visitor, but I don't know if this also applies to L-1 visa holders and I can't find any CBP documentation about how the APEC card is handled.

Comment: APEC card holders can use the relevant lane (normally the crew lane, but not always) under any circumstances. I've used it countless times for E-3 visa and even as a US Permanent Resident.

Answer (score 4):

[The answer is no.](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/eligibility)

The only eligible nationalities are:

> U.S. citizens, U.S. lawful permanent residents and citizens of the
> following countries are eligible for Global Entry membership:
>
> Citizens of Argentina
>
> Citizens of India
>
> Citizens of Colombia
>
> Citizens of United Kingdom
>
> Citizens of Germany
>
> Citizens of Panama
>
> Citizens of Singapore
>
> Citizens of South Korea
>
> Citizens of Switzerland
>
> Citizens of Taiwan
>
> Mexican nationals

Canadian citizens are technically ineligible, but can apply for the NEXUS program, which includes all benefits of Global Entry at a lower price.  However, the only interview centres available are located within Canada, or at US sites near the border.  (The furthest from the border at the time of writing is Seattle's Boeing Field.)  U.S. citizens and many permanent residents of Canada and the U.S. are also eligible.